# Рекурсивный вызов vs вызов двух методов

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
У меня такой вопрос, есть ли разница между

этим:

```
void FooMethod(object obj)
{
    /*Some code*/
    var obj2 = ...
    FooMethod(obj2);
}
```

и этим:

```
void FooMethod(object obj)
{
    FooMethod_(obj);
}

void FooMethod_(object obj)
{
    /*Some code*/
    var obj2 = ...
    FooMethod(obj2);
}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: И так, и так всё кончится `StackOverflowException`. К чему вообще вопрос?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем и целом - разницы нет. Оба выкинут StackOverflowException